# Converting PHP function to Python

Tags: php, python

Trying to convert the following PHP function to Python but getting the following error.  What would be the working Python equivalent to the below PHP function?

line 140, in doDetectBigToSmall
for scale in xrange(start_scale, scale > 1,scale = scale* scale_update):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scale' referenced before assignment

PHP CODE:

```
 protected function doDetectBigToSmall($ii, $ii2, $width, $height)  
 {  
  $s_w = $width/20.0;  
  $s_h = $height/20.0;  
  $start_scale = $s_h < $s_w ? $s_h : $s_w;  
  $scale_update = 1 / 1.2; 


        for ($scale = $start_scale; $scale > 1; $scale *= $scale_update) {  
        $w = (20*$scale) >> 0;  
        $endx = $width - $w - 1;  
        $endy = $height - $w - 1;  
        $step = max($scale, 2) >> 0;  
        $inv_area = 1 / ($w*$w);  
        for ($y = 0; $y < $endy; $y += $step) {  
            for ($x = 0; $x < $endx; $x += $step) {  
                $passed = $this->detectOnSubImage($x, $y, $scale, $ii, $ii2, $w, $width+1, $inv_area);  
                if ($passed) {  
                    return array('x'=>$x, 'y'=>$y, 'w'=>$w);  
                }  
            } // end x  
        } // end y  
    }  // end scale  
    return null;  
}
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
 def doDetectBigToSmall(self,ii, ii2, width, height):
    s_w = width/20.0
    s_h = height/20.0
    start_scale = s_h if s_h < s_w else s_w
    scale_update = 1 / 1.2
    for scale in xrange(start_scale, scale > 1,scale = scale* scale_update):
        w = (20*scale) >> 0
        endx = width - w - 1
        endy = height - w - 1
        step = max(scale, 2) >> 0
        inv_area = 1 / (w*w)

        for y in xrange(0,y < endy,y = y + step):
            for x in xrange(0, x < endx, x= x + step):
                passed = self.detectOnSubImage(x, y, scale, ii, ii2, w, width+1, inv_area)
                if (passed):
                    return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'w': w}
```

Comment: Before blindly writing Python code: Learn Python and specifically son't use methods where you have obviously never checked their sementatics.

Comment: I did check the semantics but I admit I didn't fully understand the For Loops with Range and Xrange as compared to how For Next Loops work with some other languages I've worked with.  I'm trying to learn Python and granted along the way I will make mistakes and may need some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no idea what `xrange()` does ;-)  So read the docs before you try it again.  In the meantime, replace:

```
for scale in xrange(start_scale, scale > 1,scale = scale* scale_update):
```

with

```
scale = start_scale
while scale > 1:
```

and, at the end of the loop, add:

```
    scale *= scale_update
```

All your other uses of `xrange()` are similarly broken, but you have to make *some* effort to learn what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and yes I do lack a full understanding of range and xrange in Python even after reading the docs because I'm used to For Next Loops where a condition like scale >1 is specified to stop the Loop.  However understand what you've listed here and will re-write using while.  Thank you Tim.

Comment: Use the interactive shell to explore bits of the language.  Really helps!  For example, type in `list(xrange(2, 10, 3))` and see what you get.  And glad the example helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def strpos_r(haystack, needle):
    positions = []
    position = haystack.rfind(needle)

    while position != -1:
        positions.append(position)
        haystack = haystack[:position]
        position = haystack.rfind(needle)

return positions
```

Also, functions should not really handle input errors for you. You usually just return False or let the function throw an execution error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because xrange is a function and you are passing an uninitialized value to it.  Scale will not be initialized until after xrange is run and returns a value.  Python generally used for loops to iterate over lists.  I recommend rewriting your code using while loops.